# cURL вывод части контента

Tags: php, curl

Добрый день! Возник такой вопрос, я получаю страницу через cURL и сохраняю результат в переменной.Вся страница мне вовсе не нужна, по сути, нужна всего лишь одна ячейка в таблице.

Собственно сам вопрос, есть перменная $content с контентом сайта, как из нее выдернуть нужный мне элемент, допустим таблица.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: с помощью регулярных выражений, или какой-то подходящей для этих целей библиотеки.

Comment: после получения данный , просто ипользуйте  HTML парсер, как пример PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Comment: А через strpos() никак нельзя?

Comment: @ArtemIstomin `strpos() возвращает позицию, в которой находится искомая строка, относительно начала строки`.

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм следующий:

1. Забираете страницу через `Curl`.
2. Парсите её например с помощью  [domdocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php).
3. Достаёте то, что Вам нужно.